# how to submit login form I have below, on clicking "enter" key as i fill up the credentials?

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a login form as below, I have tried doing this by onkeydown event, but i need this to work only for enter key..

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login">
<div class="login-form">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="col1">E-mail Address</li>
                            <li class="col2"><input name="email_address" type="text" class="textfiled" /></li>
                            <li class="col1">Password</li>
                            <li class="col2"><input name="password" type="password" class="textfiled" /></li>
                            <li class="col1"></li>
                            <li class="col2"><input name="signin" type="button" class="signin-btn" onclick="javascript: login.submit();" onkeydown="javascript: login.submit();"/></li>

                        </ul>
                   </div>
</form>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<li class="col2"><input name="signin" type="button" class="signin-btn" onclick="javascript: login.submit();" onkeydown="javascript: if (window.event.keyCode == 13) login.submit(); else window.event.keyCode = null; "/></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your signin button to `type="submit"`.

```
<input name="signin" type="submit" class="signin-btn" value="Submit" />
```

No need for all those `onclick` handler.